# Core-Plot graph in a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, core-plot

im trying to put a Coreplot graph in a UIView.
Some questions, should i do it in XIB? or should i do it programmically ?

If so how should i write the codes? etc.

I actually have two Classes. one called GraphView which is supposed to hold the Coreplot graph.
Another called CorePlotViewController.

Thx for looking guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm i guess i must be some real newb to ask even this type of question :/ 
but i guess i solved it .

```
CorePlotViewController *aCorePlotViewController = [[CorePlotViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CorePlotViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview :aCorePlotViewController.view];
```